# ImageView Scale Type incorrect inside of a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I have a GridView with 4 columns and n-rows.  Each cell is simply an ImageView.  My custom adapter's getView() code looks like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    //imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    if(imageLoader != null) {
        String url = randomImage();
        imageView.setContentDescription(url);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, imageView);
    }
    return imageView;
}
```

The imageLoader will pick a random URL and in the background, go fetch it and update the ImageView accordingly.  That works fine and dandy.  The problem is that the resulting images seem to be using a scale type of FIT_START instead of FIT_XY.  I'm explicitly setting this to FIT_XY and even set it again inside of the code that sets the imageView's drawable... still its not FIT_XY and i'm stumped.  Ideas?

Edited to remove the call to setAdjustViewBounds().

Comment: Because you're overriding that with the adjustViewBounds attribute. Do you actually *want* FIT_XY? I ask because it's an extreme edge case where you actually want to stretch disproportionately. If you want the image to fit within 100x100, use CENTER_CROP instead.

Comment: Ahh, I added the adjustViewBounds in there while testing.  Took it out and also changed to CENTER_CROP and I'm getting the same result.   In my case, FIT_XY would be ok because i'm guaranteed that every image will be 300x300 before scaling it.  So, its still not displaying correctly... other ideas?

Comment: FIT_XY would work, yes, but FIT_CENTER or CENTER_CROP would have the same result and be sure not to break if for some reason the wrong size image came in. Do you have a screenshot of what's happening?

Comment: Here's the gridview: http://twitpic.com/cjg0qg

Comment: Here's the image it should show in each: http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/070005aa9ade11e28f8522000a1fb838_6.jpg

Comment: Can you post the code for `DisplayImage()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just found the issue. I was using Romain Guy's code for creating a RoundedDrawable from a bitmap -- to get rounded corners, ala iOS, as shown here: curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/… ... when i skip the RoundedDrawable conversion, it works fine. Something in the RoundedDrawable code is what is throwing this whole thing off. I'll just need to find another method to round the corners of the imageview. I am using CENTER_CROP now thanks to @kcoppock ! :)

Comment: The getRoundedCornerBitmap() shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners) worked without issue.